# How to get this set of Divs to be stretchable divs on Width & Height

Tags: html

I have this set of divs in may page and I can not get the whole lot to re-size on browser window re size, I have tried to use some Jquery coding found on this site but it seems that the Divs are only resizing on width rather than on both w & H.

My image for divs is on this link:

www.beemagic.co.uk/mydiv.html

Comment: Show us your code so far so we can help. Just telling us the problem really isn't going to help us help you.

Comment: you can also add the image in the question!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what your after, from the looks of it you want the whole site to be able to be resized?

I come up with this very basic JSFiddle that shows that it can be done if that's really how you want it.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="side"></div>
        <div class="slider"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    border: green 2px solid;
}
.header {
    height: 19%;
    width: 99.6%;
    border: blue 2px solid;
    margin: 5px;
}
.content {
    height: 79%;
    width: 99.6%;
    border: red 2px solid;
    margin: 5px;
}
.side {
    height: 85%;
    width: 20%;
    border: purple 2px solid;
    margin: 5px;
}
.slider {
    height: 10%;
    width: 99%;
    border: gold 2px solid;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/dVYUZ/1/)